# Splitting sum using index notation

Tags: summation

Using index notation a sum $S=\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i b_i$ can be written without the summation symbol since $i$ is a repeated index. Is it possible to write the sum in two terms

$$S=a_1 b_1 + \sum_{i=2}^{N}a_i b_i$$

in the same way (by using a Kronecker delta or other known symbols). If so, how?

Comment: yes you can. but why would you want to do that?

Comment: @DanielY Why do you split a sum? Because you want special terms out
Why do you use index notation? To avoid having tons of summation symbols everywhere.

Comment: just asking :) what you did is legal

Comment: @DanielY Yes, but what if I do not like to write summation everywhere but just $a_i b_i=...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you could write 
$$a_ib_i=a_ib_i \delta_{i1}+a_ib_i(1-\delta_{i1})$$
But please don't do this. For one thing, I never saw Einstein convention applied when an index appeared *more* than twice. For another, the convention is just a bad idea from the beginning [/opinion].